# http post request to an api using axios in nuxtjs shwoing net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: api, axios

I have made an API using lumen and all POST,GET Methods are working well in localhost and also works GET request when hosted on live server but unfortunately POST request are not working and shows the error as 
**net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR**
The POST request is working well in POSTMAN

```js
async submitForm(){
        const config = {
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json','Accept':'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
        }
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.name);
        formData.append('email', this.email);
        formData.append('phone', this.phone);
        formData.append('message', this.message);
        await this.$axios.$post('https://myurl',formData,config)
        .then((response) => {
            this.success = 'Thank you !!';
           
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = 'Unable to submit . Please try again later .';
        });
    }
```